# Where are the standard Python modules on a Windows 10 operating system?

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, python-module

I installed Python 3.7 with default settings and I want to explore the back roads a bit. I think it will be beneficial to see what goes on in the modules that we import, however, I can't find any of them. I am assuming they aren't imported from a server or through a cloud because I imported "random" without internet a couple of times already so it has to be stored on the hard drive. Can anyone lead me to the modules?

All the answers I have found were for Linux. I never used Linux so I am unsure if they are the same or not. I know this is a similar question to others, but this is specifically for Windows 10.

Comment: `import random; print(random.__file__)` or you can check on [GitHub](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/random.py).

Comment: Some modules may be stored in a zipfile, and a few of them (like `sys`) are built into the Python executable itself.

Comment: Even though many of the _questions_ are for Linux, almost all of the answers are cross-platform. On the linked duplicate, the first one is cross-platform plus a note about Windows, the second is purely cross-platform,  the third is cross-platform plus a note about Linux. (The last one is not just Linux-only but Debian/Ubuntu-only, but then that one has 0 votes.)